# Lambda call S3 get public access block using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to verify if the public access block of my bucket `mypublicbucketname` is checked or not through Lambda function. For testing, I create a bucket and I have unchecked the public access block. So, I did this Lambda:

```
import sys
from pip._internal import main
main(['install', '-I', '-q', 'boto3', '--target', '/tmp/', '--no-cache-dir', '--disable-pip-version-check'])
sys.path.insert(0,'/tmp/')

import json
import boto3
import botocore

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print(boto3.__version__)
    print(botocore.__version__)
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = client.get_public_access_block(Bucket='mypublicbucketname')
    print("response:>>",response)
```

I updated the latest version of boto3 and botocore.

```
1.16.40 #for boto3
1.19.40 #for botocore
```

Even if I uploaded them and the function seems correct I got this exception:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchPublicAccessBlockConfiguration) when calling the GetPublicAccessBlock operation: The public access block configuration was not found
```

Someone can explain me why I have this error ?

Comment: I can confirm your results. Running the code _outside of AWS Lambda_ works fine (I was using boto3 1.16.35), but running it _within_ Lambda (using various versions of boto3) always resulted in a `null` response. The matching `put_public_access_block()` worked fine, it just seems to be affecting `get_public_access_block()`. I can't fathom why the API call would run differently under AWS Lambda. Interestingly, if I include `import logging / boto3.set_stream_logger("", logging.DEBUG)`, there is less debug info under Lambda than running it outside Lambda.

Comment: I suggest you raise a bug report on https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues -- while the problem seems to be related to running under AWS Lambda, it is likely to be related to something within boto3/botocore. Please post a link to the issue here, so we can follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For futur users. If you got the same problem with `get_public_access_block()`. Use this solution:

```
try:
        response = client.get_public_access_block(Bucket='mypublicbucketname')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchPublicAccessBlockConfiguration':
            print('No Public Access')
        else:
            print("unexpected error: %s" % (e.response))
```

for `put_public_access_block`, it works fine.